# Creating react app with acl, getting casl react t.on error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, authorization, casl

I'm just getting started with casl and it seems like I must be missing something. I created a file called `can.js` and it is exactly like the example in the [docs](https://casl.js.org/v5/en/package/casl-react):

```
import { createContext } from 'react';
import { createContextualCan } from '@casl/react';

export const AbilityContext = createContext();
export const Can = createContextualCan(AbilityContext.Consumer);
```

in my `App.tsx` I am using

```
let caslAbilities = new Ability(abilitiesJson); // from an API call returning json formatted abilities as described in docs
<AbilityContext.Provider value={caslAbilities}> 
   <Main />
</AbilityContext.Provider>
```

Then inside `Main.ts` I define some routes like this:

```
import {Can} from "../Auth/can"; // the file defined above
<Can I={"read"} a={"Post"}> // this should always be false with my test abilities json
    <Route path="/reporting">
        <ReportingHome />
    </Route>
</Can>
```

When you click the restricted route the app throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.on is not a function
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Can is not working on Routes , its just HIDE/SHOW something base on abilities you provided, for throwing error you must use at backend side.